# store ls output in variable array(bash)

Tags: shell

I want to store the each output of ls command in the variable array.
I have already tried at arbitrary directory: `var=$(ls);echo $var`
It is storing the whole file names under the directory to the variable.

I also tried other methods but it is storing each word as variable element in the array.

Is there any method to store the name of each file in a directory at different indexes of an array?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [don't use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Use a glob.

```
var=(*)
printf '[%q]\n' "${var[@]}"
```

`%q` is a bash-ism (as far as I know). `%s` would work about equallywell there except for with some odder file names.

From the Bash Reference Manual:

```
%q

Causes printf to output the corresponding argument in a format that can be reused as shell input.
```

Comment: Now you did it -- where is the `q` conversion specifier documented? I can find the `q` (quad) length modifier, but not the conversion specifier?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Bash-ism as far as I know, I probably should have mentioned that. It is in the man page and bashref.

Comment: I totally agree not to use `ls`. However, for the benefit of the OP and other readers with similar question, it's worth mentioning that `var=($(ls))` will work. And maybe a little explanation regarding the syntax `var=( list of values )`.

Comment: @alvits Except it doesn't work if any of the files contain any spaces or shell metacharacters in their names and so it really just shouldn't be done (especially not when a glob works). Talking about the `var=(...)` syntax could be reasonable but I'm not sure that's usefully relevant here (the OP knows it works, etc.).